# Jquery validation - Ajax call if condition add rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I wrote the logic to check for a valid ID using the code below. It works fine with default logic using https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Now, there is an additional rule to check and show a validation message based on the AJAX call response if the content is true.

I added the below rule to display an error message if the content is true. flow is going there, but the validation message is not showing. Please let me know whether any syntax is missing?

```js
{
 "id": "4974635f-514e-4d26-8170-ae77c984e8ab",
 "content": "true",
 "status": "SUCCESS",
 "redirect": null
}

$.validator.addMethod('IDNumber', function (value) { 
    return  /^[STFGstfg]\d{7}[a-zA-Z]$/.test(value); 
}, 'Please enter a valid ID number');

$("#signup--form").validate({
    rules:{
        "id-no": {
              required: true,
              IDNumber: true
        }
    },
    messages:{
        "id-no":{
            required: 'Please enter a valid ID number'
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function submitHandler() {
      var checkID = $('#id-no').val();
      var getDomainName = window.location.origin;
      $.ajax({
          url: getDomainName + '/.rest/stripe/v1?id=' +checkID,
          type:'GET',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response) {
            if(response.content == 'false'){
               popupSubmit();
            } else{
                $('#id-no').rules('add', {
                    messages: {
                        required: 'ID no. is blacklisted. Please try with another valid ID'
                    }
                });
            }
          }
       });
       return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<form id="signup--form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="input-field--wrapper">
                <div class="title">
                    ID of the subscriber
                </div>
                <input class="form-control" value="" placeholder="D1234567U" id="id-no" name="id-no" autocomplete="off" required/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="button button-primary">Confirm</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: is ajax call firing and does it return true?

Comment: Yes Ali! Only thing validation message is not displaying like show as default validation message

Comment: Seems you are just adding the rule without executing a validation after adding the rule. Am I true?

Comment: Yes. i think so. Sorry, i am not sure how to add the rules after the AJAX call. I saw this solution in stackoverflow and tried to implement it pls